# List all duplicate posts through mySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I list all posts that are in wp_posts and have the same post_title?

Comment: Assuming that wp_posts is from WordPress, it may also contain post revisions and pages or menus (and now custom types) that have the same post_title but that are not duplicate posts.  You might need to filter these from Johan's query below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account `BrokenCrust`'s comment

> Assuming that wp_posts is from WordPress, it may also contain post revisions and pages or menus (and now custom types) that have the same post_title but that are not duplicate posts.

```
SELECT p1.* FROM wp_post p1 
INNER JOIN wp_post p2 ON (p1.id <> p2.id 
                      AND p1.post_title = p2.post_title
                      AND p1.revisions = p2.revisions
                      AND p1.page = p2.page)
```

If you don't want to see repeats in your list do

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.post_title FROM wp_post p1 
INNER JOIN wp_post p2 ON (p1.id <> p2.id AND p1.post_title = p2.post_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts p 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = p.post_title) > 1
```

Comment: Is your DB indexed?  Did you try EXPLAIN?

Comment: Just put EXPLAIN in front of any query, like `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM wp_posts p WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = p.post_title) > 1`. This should give you further information about what could cause the delay, for example if it can't use an index for the query.

Comment: Do: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM wp_posts p WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = p.post_title) > 1`

Comment: This is what I got
`1  PRIMARY  p  ALL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  60641  Using where`

`2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  wp_posts  ALL  yarpp_title  NULL  NULL  NULL  60641  Using where`

What does it mean ?